# Countdown of between two datetime using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, countdown

I have two dates as like one is 2016-02-23 15:12:12 and another one is 2016-02-29 18:16:42 then how to display hh:mm:ss countdown to subtract this two dates using jquery 
Please help Thanks in advance

Comment: This should point you in the right direction. https://jsfiddle.net/gabrieleromanato/dkerj/

Answer (score 3):

You try like this

```
var timer;

var compareDate = new Date();
compareDate.setDate(compareDate.getDate() + 7); //just for this demo today + 7 days

timer = setInterval(function() {
  timeBetweenDates(compareDate);
}, 1000);

function timeBetweenDates(toDate) {
  var dateEntered = toDate;
  var now = new Date();
  var difference = dateEntered.getTime() - now.getTime();

  if (difference <= 0) {

    // Timer done
    clearInterval(timer);

  } else {

    var seconds = Math.floor(difference / 1000);
    var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    var days = Math.floor(hours / 24);

    hours %= 24;
    minutes %= 60;
    seconds %= 60;

    $("#days").text(days);
    $("#hours").text(hours);
    $("#minutes").text(minutes);
    $("#seconds").text(seconds);
  }
}
```

or

you can use `countDownjs`

http://countdownjs.org/demo.html

Note : better to use 3rd party library because someone wrote code for this you better plug it and start using do not waste time when you have some resource for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
var date1="2016-02-12 15:12:12";
var date2="2016-02-22 18:16:42";
var d1= date1.split(" ");
d1=d1[1];
var d2= date2.split(" ");
d2=d2[1];
d1=d1.split(":");
d2=d2.split(":");
var hours=d2[0]-d1[0];
var mins=d2[1]-d1[1];
var sec=d2[2]-d1[2];
var countdown=hours+":"+mins+":"+sec;
console.log(countdown);
```

this will give you time remaining.there are some libs for time countdown.you can use use them

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
   
   $("#imar_timer<?php echo $IMAR;?>").countdown("<?php echo $timerDate; ?>", function(event) {
    var totalHours = event.offset.totalDays * 24 + event.offset.hours;
    $(this).html(event.strftime(totalHours+':%M:%S'));
   });
   
</script>`


`<div class="timer"><h2 id="imar_timer<?php echo $IMAR;?>"></h2></div>`


i have this code but its give differeance bettwen current local datetime and timerDate but i need differeance between current server time and timerDate value  Where timerDate contain future datetime of php

Comment: please see updated ans

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems you're looking to solve here.

1. How do you get the difference between two `Date` objects in javascript
2. How do you display that difference in hours, minutes, seconds

## Get difference between two `Date` objects in javascript

First, you need to get the *Unix timestamp* of each `Date` object, which is the total number of elapsed seconds from the epoch. Then you can subtract these two values to get the total difference in seconds. To do this we rely on `Date`'s [`getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) method, which in javascript returns the number of milliseconds since the epoch.

```
var start = new Date('2016-02-12 15:12:12');
var end   = new Date('2016-02-22 18:16:42');
/* This gives us an integer value of the difference in seconds */
var diff  = Math.round((end.getTime() - start.getTime()) / 1000);
```

## Display the difference in hours, minutes, and seconds

The second part requires doing some basic [clock arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) to get the number of hours, minutes, and seconds from the `diff` value.

Since there are 3600 seconds in an hour, the total number of hours in this value are `Math.floor(diff / 3600)`. Since there are 60 seconds in every minute, the total number of minutes in this value are `Math.floor((diff - (hours * 3600)) / 60)`, where `diff` is less the number of hours multiplied by `3600`. Subsequently the total number of seconds in this value are just the remainder of the `diff`, less hours and minutes, from the quotient 60 `((diff - hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60) % 60)`, which we get from the [modulus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators).

```
function getClock(seconds) {
    var hours = Math.floor(diff / 3600);
    diff -= hours * 3600
    var minutes = Math.floor(diff / 60);
    diff -= minutes * 60;
    var seconds = diff % 60;
    return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
}
```

## Putting it all together

If you want to display countdown clocks like this there are some nifty jquery plugins [jQuery Countdown](https://github.com/hilios/jQuery.countdown) which make this process a lot easier. But I felt it important to explain the details behind the programming, none-the-less.